# Systemd's Networkd: Unable to add ipv6 default route

Tags: routing, ipv6, subnet, netplan, systemd-networkd

I am having a hell of a time getting IPv6 address connectivity set up on my new VPS. I thought I knew what I was doing but apparently networkd disagrees, I keep getting issues when trying to add a default route.

Here is the networking information provided to me by my ISP:

```
Subnet      2001:19f0:6:2::/64
Gateway     2001:19f0:6::1
Nameserver  2001:4860:4860::8888
Nameserver  2001:4860:4860::8844

Interface:       ens3
OS:              Ubuntu 18.04.02
Systemd version: 237
```

**Current Setup**

I can easily set up my IP address and add a route to the gateway with the following systemd file:

```
[Match]
Name=ens3

[Network]
Address=209.222.17.197/26
Gateway=209.222.17.193
DNS=8.8.8.8

[Network]
Address=2001:19f0:6:2::1337/64

[Route]
Destination=2001:19f0:6::1
```

I get no errors in journalctl, I can successfully ping `2001:19f0:6::1`, but of course I don't have a default gateway or internet access. I can easily use `2001:19f0:6::1` as my default gateway with the following command:
`sudo ip -6 route add default via 2001:19f0:6::1`

This gives me full ipv6 routing, I can ping `ipv6.google.com`.

**The Problem**

I can't seem to get the default gateway set up in networkd, I've spent so many hours trying different combinations of options I think this might be a bug. For example, if I amend my configuration to look like this:

```
[Match]
Name=ens3

[Network]
Address=209.222.17.197/26
Gateway=209.222.17.193
DNS=8.8.8.8

[Network]
Address=2001:19f0:6:2::1337/64

[Route]
Destination=2001:19f0:6::1

[Route]
Gateway=2001:19f0:6::1
GatewayOnlink=true
```

I get the following error in the journalctl log:

```
May 27 19:31:46 public-NY systemd-networkd[2452]: ens3: Could not set route: No route to host
```

I always see that damn error "no route to host", if there's no route to `2001:19f0:6::1` then why the hell can I ping it?!

I'm fed up with this issue, but I'd like to use netplan and therefore systemd-networkd for my networking. Am I just doing something stupid or is something as critical as networkd really this broken?

Comment: Destination is a network with prefix. I assume you should do something like: [Route]
Destination=2001:19f0:6::/48
Gateway=2001:19f0:6::1 When you can pink it you have already a route. ip -6 route show would be help full.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the `GatewayOnLink` that's causing the problem, because as far as I can see, that gateway is not on link.  Your on-link subnet is `2001:19f0:6:2::/64`, while the gateway address is not in that subnet -- the `/64` that it is in is `2001:19f0:6:0::/64 (extra`:0` added for clarity).

Now, how you can manage to ping that gateway address I couldn't tell you -- most likely it's being picked up via RA, which is odd, but not unknown, in a hosting environment -- but in any event, it's not an on-link route, and so therefore networkd is, quite rightly, telling you there is no route to that host using the parameters you have given.

Comment: The `GatewayOnlink=yes` is required in some cases, even if the gateway address is not in the subnet. As an example, my on-link subnet is HE tunnel routed prefix 2001:470:19:400::/64, while my gateway is 2001:470:18:402::1/64; but I have to add `GatewayOnlink=yes` to add the default route and gain IPv6 connectivity. This might be a networkd bug; see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495038/324313.